# ls regular expression grep line ending with 777 files

Tags: regex, grep, chmod, ls, access-rights

There is a little issue that makes me crazy.

Let me try to explain it with a small example.

I have/touch 3 files:

> foo.xyz
>  bar.xyz
>  foo.bar

I change the mode to **777** of *foo.xyz* (`chmod 777 foo.xyz`), the other remains 640. Now I want to use `ls` to list all the files and use `grep` to search for a specific one. 
There i want to exlcude the xyz files from the list

```
ls -alh | grep -Ev xyz$
```

The `$` character at the end drives me crazy. Somehow, the **777** file remains in the list outputed. Normally i would expect, that all of the xyz files are excluded, but somehow the **777** file is not.

This is just a minimal example, normally i do have a lot additinal grep's in there ;-).

Can you explain, where i do have a error in my thinking?

Comment: Take the dollar off - it is requiring the `xyz`  to occur at the right-hand **end** of the line.

Comment: yes, i want to drop files which have xyz in the end

Comment: Try `ls -alh | grep -Ev xyz$ | cat -vet` to see hidden characters.

Comment: For me, the '777' is filtered out as expected. What about trying `/bin/ls` instead of just `ls`?

Comment: 1000 times thank you @MarkSetchell & tif:
Both of your answers where going in the same directions. 777 files are highlighted at my configuration in green (`alias ls = ls --color=always`). This means, that the line does not end with xyz but with **xyz^[[0m**. Keeping this in mind, i was able to adapt my grep. Thank you!

Comment: You can also enable *"extended globbing"* with `shopt -s extglob`. Then you can use `ls !(*.xyz)`

Comment: See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Comment: Note I could not repro on Ubuntu 16.04.